# How can i set a string to zero after an expired time?

Tags: php, string, random

I am creating a login/registration-script where a user hast to activate his account with a token. Now i have a function that calls a random string.

> class.functions.php

```
public static function generateRandomString($length = 200) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

this will output something like this: `jTq7tH4dKy66dmnhRev5EjbZDZygN1...` 

**now my question is, how can i set this string empty after 24h, so that the user has to activate his account again.**

my thought was about an `update query` in my database like this:

```
$statusN = "N" and $statusY = "Y"
```

the table field from the database:

```
`user_status` ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
```

the sql statment:

```
$sql = "UPDATE formular SET user_status='" . $statusY . "' WHERE user_status='" . $statusN . "'";
```

**but i dont know how to handel it with the time**

Here is the inserting of the userdata and the `activation_token`

> register.php

```
$activationToken = functions::generateRandomString();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO formular (firstname, second_firstname, lastname, zipcode, city, street, additionaladdress, country_id_from_apps_countries, username, email, hash, dday, dmonth, dyear, religion, housenumber, activation_token) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssisssssssssssss", $firstname, $secondFirstname, $lastname, $zipcode, $city, $street, $additionaladdress, $country, $username, $email, $hash, $DOB, $MOB, $YOB, $religion, $houseNumber, $activationToken);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {

    }
```

Comment: Insert a timestamp also, and include that in your query.

Comment: Add a `activate_by` column. Then if the activation is not done before that time, dont allow the activation from the activateion script

Comment: okay thanks for that hint i'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the timestamp and creating the string are two different things.

On one side, you have to create the string and save it with the actual timestamp.

On a second step, probably with a cronJob you have to check wich tokens in your DB are expired (more than 24 hours old) and set them to null.

You have two different operations in two different pieces of code.

To disable all expired entries, just do a SELECT * from .... where token >= XXX. Foreach result, UPDATE table set token = NULL where ....

and so on.